# Longest vector spanned by unit-normalized basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, projective-geometry

I'm trying to understand the length of the longest vector that a basis with certain properties could span.

Problem statement: Fix a euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a fixed scalar $\epsilon > 0$. Consider a basis $\mathcal{B} = \{v_1,v_2,....,v_n\}$ such that $\forall i$ $||v_i||_2 = 1$ and for any $i,j$ $|v_i \cdot v_j| < \cos {\theta_o}$ where $\theta_o \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ is a fixed angle. Now, consider an arbitrary vector $p$ such that for any $i$ $|p\cdot v_i| < \epsilon$. Then, (conjecture) the maximum norm of $p$ is bounded as $||p||_2 \le C_o\cdot \sqrt{n}\cdot \epsilon$ where $C_o$ depends only on $\theta_0$.

Some approach: If $\theta_o = \pi/2$, then the bound on the norm of $p$ is $\sqrt{n}\cdot \epsilon$. Now, it is unclear if the stated bound holds if $\theta_o$ is smaller. I tried considering the projection map $\mathbb{P}_{-i}$ defined by the subspace spanned by $\mathcal{B} \setminus v_i$ and then consider the length of $\mathbb{P}_{-i} p$. Idea is to use induction but then the bound on $\mathbb{P}_{-i} p$ is $C_o\cdot \sqrt{n-1}\cdot \epsilon$ (which would be weak). I'm completely sure if the stated bound is correct. It could be that I'm missing some easy result to wrap this up. If there is some other bound which beats the $\sqrt{n}$ factor it would be interesting to see.

Additional assumption: I've also been trying to impose some additional structure on the basis vectors e.g. If for any $i$ $|\mathbb{P}_{-i} v_i \cdot v_i| < \cos {\theta_o}$. This would make the cone defined by the basis vectors more symmetric and some corner cases could be eliminated. Can we show the stated bound using this additional assumption?

Answer (score 0):

**[Post edited]**

Matters are as conjectured.

For easing the arguments below, let $n$ even.

First, notice that you can do the following construction. Let $e = (1,1,\cdots, 1)$ be the vector of all ones, and $u_i$ be the $i$th unit vector.  Then let the base vectors $v_i = a u_i + b e$. We can determine the constants $a$ and $b$ such that $v_i^2=a^2 + 2ab + nb^2= 1$ and $v_i v_j = 2ab + n b^2 = \cos(\theta_0)$ with equality for all $i \ne j$, giving
$a = \sqrt{1 - \cos(\theta_0)}$ and $b =  \frac{1}{n} (\sqrt{1 +(n-1) \cos(\theta_0)} -  \sqrt{1 - \cos(\theta_0)})$

(conjecture) With this base, one vector with the largest norm is  $p = c (\sum_{i=1}^{n/2} v_i - \sum_{j=1+n/2}^{n} v_j) $. The two halves of the base vectors can actually be assigned randomly to the two sums.

Then you have $|p v_k|=c( 1 - \cos(\theta_0))$ for all $k$, so you can actually equate this to $\epsilon$. This gives $$
c = \frac{\epsilon}{1 - \cos(\theta_0)}
$$
Further, you have
$$
p^2 = c^2 (\sum_{i=1}^{n/2} v_i - \sum_{j=1+n/2}^{n} v_j )^2 = c^2 n (1 - \cos(\theta_0))
$$
Hence you obtain
$$
||p||_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \cos(\theta_0)}} \sqrt{n} \epsilon = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} \cdot \sin(\theta_0/2)} \sqrt{n} \epsilon
$$

For $\theta_0 = \pi/2$, this gives
$
||p||_2 (\theta_0 = \pi/2)= \sqrt{n}  \epsilon
$
as you already stated.

In general, the behavior of $||p||_2$ is as conjectured, with the constant $C_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} \cdot \sin(\theta_0/2)}$ depending only on $\theta_0$. $\qquad \Box$

Comment: Dear @andreas, Thanks for your reply. From your construction, it is clear that $\sqrt{n}$ factor can be beaten. It is still not clear if the bound $C_o\cdot \sqrt{n}\cdot \epsilon$ is safe i.e. in any case the stated upper bound is valid? Do you think there could be counterexamples where $||p|| > C_o\cdot \sqrt{n}\cdot \epsilon$?

Comment: No, I don't think we can actually construct cases with $||p||_2 >  C_o\cdot \sqrt{n}\cdot \epsilon$. I would even conjecture that the construction I gave leads to a "best" upper bound, which is then $||p||_2 \le \frac{\sqrt{(n + (n^2-n)\cos(\theta_0))}}{1 + (n-1) \cos(\theta_0)} \epsilon$ as stated.

Comment: I'm not sure if the bound you suggest would hold. For example, if we  consider n= 2 then your conjectured bound is $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{1+\cos{\theta_o}}}\epsilon \le \sqrt{2}\epsilon$ if $\theta_o < \pi/2$. But it is not difficult to see that one can pick a vector in the cone defined by the orthogonal vectors of the two basis vectors and then the length of $p$ could be $\frac{\epsilon}{\sin{(\theta_o/2)}}$. So, it doesn't seem your conjectured bound holds. I hope I'm not making any mistake.

Comment: If $n=2$ then you can write $p = a v_1 + b v_2$. Could you demonstrate a choice of constants $a,b$ such that $|p\cdot v_i| < \epsilon$ and $||p||_2  > \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{1+\cos{\theta_o}}}\epsilon $ ?

Comment: It could be constructed easily. Let $v_1 = u_1$ and $v_2 = \sin{\theta_o}u_1 + \cos{\theta_o}u_2$. Now consider, $p$ to have angle $\frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{\theta_o}{2}$. Note such a $p$ would have same absolute dot product with $v_1$ and $v_2$. Now, $|p\cdot v_1| = |||p||_2\cos{(\pi/2 + \theta_o/2)}| = ||p||_2\sin{\theta_o/2} < \epsilon$. Thus, in limit $|||p||_2 \to \frac{\epsilon}{\sin{\theta_o/2}}$. Now, one has to pick a $\theta_o$ such that $\sin{\theta_o/2} < 1/\sqrt{2}$ and then the bound above wouldn't hold.

Comment: I definitely made a mistake in stating earlier that the vector with the largest norm is $p = c \sum_i v_i$. I edited the post to come up with a new conjecture which changes matters dramatically ... please check if you find that plausible.

Comment: Hi, $p = \cos{(\pi/2 + \theta_o/2)}u_1 + \cos{(\theta_0/2)}u_2$. I hope I'm clear now.

Comment: The current bound seems to work fine for smaller $n$ values. It would be interesting to see if we could prove it for any pathological arrangement of the basis vectors with minimum $\theta_o$ condition. You seem to suggest that it indeed is the case, why do you think so? Since your construction analyses very symmetric arrangement, it may happen that one could construct some pathological case to beat the bound.

Comment: I guess I made a mistake. $v_2 = \cos{\theta_o}u_1 + \sin{\theta_o}u_2$. Now, it should work.

Comment: Yeah, your current bound works for $n=2$. As I pointed before, it is not very clear if there aren't any pathological cases for $n > 2$ where the bound couldn't be beaten.

Comment: Yes you said that before and that may be the case. I don't have ideas for such pathological cases right now, but I'd be happy to discuss if you can come up with examples.

Comment: One pathological case for $n=3$ could be of this form: Consider $v_1 = u_1$ and $v_2$ is in the x-y-plane with angle $\theta_o$.  Let $v^{'}_3$ is in the same plane but makes $\theta_o$ with $v_2$. Now consider $v_3$ with non-zero z-component whose projection is along $v^{'}_3$ in the x-y-plane. Note, $v_3$ indeed makes minimum $\theta_o$ angle with $v_1$ and $v_2$.  Now, consider the $u_3$; it is $\perp$ to $v_1$ and $v_2$ and we can make the angle between $u_3$ and $v_3$ close to $\pi/2$. Thus, one can extend $u_3$ to obtain $p$ which could beat the bound you suggest.

Comment: I guess to make your construction work we need to assume some more regularity conditions as I have suggested in the original post.

Comment: "pathological case for n=3": I restricted my post to even  $n$, since then arguments work out nicely.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that for even $n$, the same argument would hold. I have a proposition that if the minimum volume cone defined by the directions (that of the basis vectors) contain a symmetric cone of angle $\theta_o$, then the conjectured bound could hold for general $n$.

Comment: Hi @andreas, your construction for $n$ to be even is wrong. You can't solve the equations to find $a$ and $b$ in the form you suggest (you could see yourself if you write the equations to solve for them).

Comment: Hi, I put the expressions to be solved, and the solutions for $a$ and $b$, in the main text.